# Outlook Flagged(tasked) emails response

Tags: vba

Daily I receive tons of emails, maximum of which needs to be worked upon and some are follow up emails.
I am using the flagged mode to track the important emails and replying them and simultaneously clearing the flags, and sometimes I forget hence I have to go to the sent item and search by email's subject line and take action accordingly.

I am looking for a code which will help me in:-
1.Macro will iterate through all the flagged emails in inbox.

2.Then it will check the sent on time (received time of the email in inbox)

3.Thereafter it will check the sent items whether the email has been replied (re: Subject) or forwarded (fw:subject) and with the senton time.

4.If the sent time is more than > received time (of the flagged emails) then  **msgbox**:- ***Email has been replied***
otherwise it will pop up a **msgbox**:- ***Email*** **has not been replied, do you want to reply?,** if yes, then it will reply the existing email with write function.

I do have written a code,it is working but I am not getting any response, nor pop up emails nor any bug fixing pop ups.your response will be highly appreciated :-

```
Sub trial()
On Error Resume Next
Dim objfolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim objfolder2 As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim objfolder2 As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim objfolder1 As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim objns As Outlook.NameSpace`Dim objitem As Outlook.MailItem`
Dim objitem1 As Outlook.MailItem
Dim objvariant As Variant
Dim objvariant1 As Variant
Dim obsubject As Variant

Dim obsubject1 As Variant

Dim sendtime As Variant

Dim sendtime1 As Variant
Dim obfollowupmail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim strpromt As Variant
Dim nresponse As Integer

Set objns = Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
'declaring inbox

Set objinbox = objns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
'declaring sent

Set objfolder1 = objns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)
For Each objitem In objinbox

If objinbox.DefaultItemType = olMailItem Then
If objitem.Class = olMail Then
If objitem = IsMarkedAsTask Then


Set objvaraiant = objinbox.Items
Set obsubject = LCase(objvariant.Subject)
Set sendtime = objvariant.SentOn



obsubject1 = "re: &subject"

For Each obsubject1 In objfolder1
Set objvariant1 = objfolder1.Items
Set sendtime1 = obsubject1.SentOn
If sendtime1 > sendtime Then
MsgBox ("Message has been replied for" & obsubject)
Else
strpromt = "you haven't received the reply of" & obsubject
nresponse = MsgBox(vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Confirm to send a follow up email?")
If nresponse = vbYes Then
Set obfollowupmail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
With obfollowupmail
.Display




Set objitem = Nothing
Set obfolder = Nothing
Set objinbox = Nothing
Set objns = Nothing

End With
End If
End If

Next


End If
End If
End If

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, pleade update on the request.

Comment: Hi all.. Please assist